# C++ Casting a pointer in a new?

Tags: c++

I have this line of code which I cannot make sense of.

```
ClassA *pointer= new( ( char* )BASE_ADDRESS)ClassA ;
```

What does this cast `( ( char* )BASE_ADDRESS)` even mean?

`BASE_ADDRESS` is some memory location.

Comment: It's a "placement new expression".

Comment: Read about 'placement new' http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: You will probably find all you need to know about using placement-new [from **this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new).

Comment: _@H.Sock_ Add a bit more context please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax). It constructs an object of type `ClassA` and puts it in the memory location specified by `BASE_ADDRESS`.